I don't know how to solve this NULL pointer exception while using pojo class with Pagefactory
I was using Pojo class in my project and i have used PageFactory.initElements to initialize the elements. But when i try to sendkeys or click the element it throws null poniter exception. Please help me to get through this one.. thank you
I tried with pagefactory class to intialize the elemets. I except the element is working properly without any exception
MY POJO Class:
public class LoginPojo extends BaseClass {
public LoginPojo() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(id = "username")
private WebElement txtUser;
@FindBy(id = "password")
private WebElement txtPass;
@FindBy(id="login")
private WebElement btnLogin;

public WebElement getTxtUser() {
    return txtUser;
}
public WebElement getTxtPass() {
    return txtPass;
}
public WebElement getBtnLogin() {
    return btnLogin;
}

}
My main Class:
public class AdactinHotel extends BaseClass {
LoginPojo loginPojo = new LoginPojo();

@Test(priority = 0)
public void launchBrowser() throws IOException {
    driverSetup(getProjectFileValue("browser"));
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void urlSetup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    launchURL(getProjectFileValue("url"));
    maximizeWindow();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void login() throws IOException {
    elementSendKeys(loginPojo.getTxtUser(), getProjectFileValue("user"));
    elementSendKeys(loginPojo.getTxtPass(), getProjectFileValue("pass"));
    elementClick(loginPojo.getBtnLogin());
}

}
BaseClass:
public class BaseClass {
public WebDriver driver;
public void driverSetup(String browser) {
    switch (browser) {
    case "chrome":
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
        ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
        break;

    case "edge":
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        break;
        
    default:
        break;
    } 
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
    ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
}

public void launchURL(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

public void maximizeWindow() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public void elementSendKeys(WebElement element, String text) {
            element.sendKeys(text);
}

public void elementClick(WebElement element) {
    element.click();
}

public String getProjectPath() {
    String property = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    return property;
}
 
public String getProjectFileValue(String key) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getProjectPath()+"\\Configuration\\config.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);
    Object object = properties.get(key);
    String value = (String)object;
    System.out.println(value);
    return value;
}

Exception:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
chrome
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Dec 11, 2024 11:28:08 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 131
Dec 11, 2024 11:28:08 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 131.0.6778.109. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.12.0 where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
Dec 11, 2024 11:28:09 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 131
Dec 11, 2024 11:28:09 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 131.0.6778.109. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.12.0 where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
https://adactinhotelapp.com
null
PASSED: launchBrowser
PASSED: urlSetup
FAILED: login
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
at com.baseclass.BaseClass.elementSendKeys(BaseClass.java:50)
at com.adactin.main.AdactinHotel.login(AdactinHotel.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
